# Onclick function using switch cases

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onclick

I want to make a search bar and in such a way that if i write different organisations name (Deloitte, TCS, Wipro, etc) and then click on search button, then the official site of that organisation will open.

html code

```
<input type="text" id="org_name" class="form-control border-light" style="padding: 30px 25px;"
                        placeholder="Organisation Name.." list="list01">
<div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary px-4 px-lg-5" id="search_org" onclick="organisation()">Search</button>
                    </div>
```

javascript code

```
function organisation(){
var org; 
var org = document.getElementById("org_name").value;
switch(org){
    case "Deloitte":
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www2.deloitte.com"></a>
 }
}
```

i have written only one case but that too is not giving any result.

Comment: try to modify your code
`switch(org){
    case "Deloitte":
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www2.deloitte.com"></a>
 }`

to

`switch(org){
    case "Deloitte":
      window.open("https://www2.deloitte.com");
      break;`

to open window you need to use `window.open function`

Answer (score 0):

the following seems to work, update part of you switch with following

```js
 case "Deloitte":
     window.location = 'https://www2.deloitte.com'
```

btw, if you need prepared list of companies, look up [mdn wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

Answer (score 0):

```
    function organisation() {
        var org = document.getElementById("org_name").value;
        switch (org) {
            case "Deloitte":

                window.open('http://www.Deloitte.org', '_blank');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the site to open a new window/tab you should use [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) but I suggest that you look at the section on [accessibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#accessibility) too as that gives you hints on why you shouldn't (or in some instances) can't use it.

Taking your code

1. Cache the elements up front
2. Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add a listener to an element - inline JS is not recommended practice in 2022 and it's better to learn good habits as you're just starting out.
3. Put the value you get from the input into lower case, and then test for those cases in your switch. No-one really adds the proper case into search bars, and expect the code to fill in the gaps.
4. Include a `default` case in your `switch` to catch any values that don't match the other cases.

Note: the snippet won't work because SO blocks the code and returns an error so I've included a working copy [over on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sm1udw0j/1/).

```js
   
// Cache the elements
const org = document.getElementById('org_name');
const button = document.getElementById('search_org');

// Add the listener to call a `search` function
button.addEventListener('click', search);

function search() {
  
  // Take the value from your input and coerce it
  // to lower case
  switch (org.value.toLowerCase()) {
    
    // And test for those lower case options
    case 'deloitte': {
      window.open('https://www2.deloitte.com');
      break;
    }

    // Make sure you include a `default` case to catch
    // any values that don't match
    default: {
      console.log('No match');
      break;
    }
  
  }

}
```

```css
#org_name { padding: 30px 25px; }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="org_name" placeholder="Organisation Name..">
<button id="search_org">Search</button>
```